# React.js, correct way to iterate inside DOM

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state-saving

Im new in ReactJS...

I have a project with the following class components structure:

```
index.js
  --app
    --chat
  --header
  --left
  --right
```

In the chat.js component, I make a google search with the api to retrieve images based on specific keyword... My intuitive solution was:

```
this.client.search("cars")
                .then(images => {
                    for(let el of images) {
                    ReactDOM.render(<img src="{{el.url}}" syle="{{width: '100%'}}" />, document.querySelector('#gimages'));
                    }
                });
```

It is correct? Or I may to use Components with stored states with flux (redux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler more conventional use of react would achieve what your require?

You could follow a pattern similar to that shown below to achieve what you require in a more "react-like" way:

```
class Chat extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { images : [] } // Set the inital state and state
                                 // model of YourComponent
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Assume "client" has been setup already, in your component

    this.client.search("cars")
    .then(images => {

      // When a search query returns images, store those in the
      // YourComponent state. This will trigger react to re-render 
      // the component
      this.setState({ images : images })
    });
  }

  render() {

    const { images } = this.state

    // Render images out based on current state (ie either empty list, 
    // no images, or populated list to  show images)
    return (<div>
        { 
          images.map(image => {
              return <img src={image.url} style="width:100%" />
          })
        }
    </div>)
  }

}
```

Note that this is not a complete code sample, and will require you to "fill in the gaps" with what ever else you have in your current Chat component (ie setting up `this.client`)

Comment: `images.map(image => (<img src={image.url}` map function is failing here...

Comment: What error do you get ? Have just updated answer if you want to retry that. Added missing )

Comment: I got `TypeError: images.map is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, seems like Google dont return array... So I converted it with `Array.from(this.state.images)`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way you should go, you don't need to use `ReactDOM.render` for each item. Actually, you don't need to use `ReactDOM.render` at all. In your component you can use a life-cycle method to fetch your data, then set it to your local state. After getting data you can pass this to an individual component or directly render in your `render` method.

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
  state = {
    images: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.client.search( "cars" )
      .then( images => this.setState( { images } ) );
  }

  renderImages = () =>
      this.state.images.map( image => <Image key={image.id} image={image} /> );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.renderImages()}</div>
    );
  }
}

const Image = props => (
  <div>
    <img src={props.image.url} syle="{{width: '100%'}}" />
  </div>
);
```

At this point, you don't need Redux or anything else. But, if you need to open your state a lot of components, you can consider it. Also, get being accustomed to using methods like `map`, `filter` instead of for loops.